# R: replace values in a data frame applying a function, including a calculation

Tags: r

I'm currently struggling on the following topic:

I downloaded weekly data for an index from Yahoo finance. It correctly pulls data for every Monday, but it states it as Sundays (even tough the data is for Monday).

```
# a quick fix would just be:
SMI$Date <- SMI$Date+1
```

Nevertheless, I would like to use a function that does this automatically if the weekdays are Sundays instead of Mondays.

I tried the following approaches, but they both didn't work.

```
# approach 1:
CheckDateYahoo1 <- function(datex){
for(i in length(datex)){
if(weekdays(datex[i])=="Sunday"){
datex[i] <- datex[i]+1
} else {
datex[i] <- datex[i]
}
}
}
```

Applying this function, just nothing happens.

```
# approach 2:
CheckDateYahoo2 <- function(datex){
if(weekdays(datex)=="Sunday"){
datex <- datex+1
}else{
datex <- datex
}
}
```

Applying this function, i get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (weekdays(datex) == "Sunday") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I think that I made some obvious mistakes in the code for the function as I am new to R - could you help me out on that?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: rather than try this work around, you're better off working out what's causing Mondays to become Sundays, as this could be causing trouble elsewhere that you don't know about

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation of your problems

You don't `return` anything from these functions. Even though you don't need an explicit `return()` call in R functions (though I highly recommend it), you have to at least use implicit return. For example, compare

```
func1 <- function(x) {
    x <- x + 1
}
```

with

```
func2 <- function(x) {
    x <- x + 1
    x
}

func1(5)
# Nothing happens

func2(5)
# [1] 6
```

Additionally, in your second function, you feed `if()` a logical vector of the same length as `datex`, which it isn't designed to do. For example, compare

```
if ( TRUE ) {
    print('yes')
}
# [1] "yes"
```

with

```
if ( c(FALSE, TRUE) ) {
    print('yes')
}
# Warning message:
# In if (c(FALSE, TRUE)) { :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

### Solution

You could try a function like the following:

```
check_date <- function(dates) {
    dates[weekdays(dates) == 'Sunday'] <- dates[weekdays(dates) == 'Sunday'] + 1
    return(dates)
}
```

This seemed to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
# Make some example data
dates <- as.Date(paste0('2017-11-', 1:7))
# Check the weekdays
weekdays(dates)
# [1] "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"   
# [7] "Tuesday" 
# And try our function
check_date(dates)
# [1] "2017-11-01" "2017-11-02" "2017-11-03" "2017-11-04" "2017-11-06" "2017-11-06"
# [7] "2017-11-07"
weekdays(check_date(dates))
# [1] "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Monday"    "Monday"   
# [7] "Tuesday"
```